# Can I use deep links for Google Data Studio report and/or pass data source parameters in the report URL?

Tags: looker-studio

Is it possible to build one Google data studio report (i.e., template) and use a URL that links it to a specific data-set or defines a hidden filter that creates a sample of a larger data set?

I understand [Data Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7415591)  allows this for users operating under the same Google domain.

However, I want to provide multiple university student teams with their personal information but not allow the other teams to see or filter for information that they should not see. Ideally I could simply share a customised URL with each team that takes care of this filtering/sampling.

Any guidance appreciated - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [custom bookmarks](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7664330?hl=en) and [URL parameters](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters).